# Getting screenshot when view is opaque

Tags: ios, screenshot

I'm trying to get a screenshot of my app. The problem is as follows:

I have a transparent view and on top of it the is a `GLView` which is opaque (= YES). So the screen is actually black when the app is running. When using `renderInContext` on the main window I get the correct image with one difference, the background is white.

Is there a way to bypass this problem?